# Синонимы союзов "или", "либо"

Tags: союзы, синонимы

При перечислении какими словами ещё можно продолжить связывать сказанное ранее, дополняя вариациями?
*Либо* [x], *или* [y], ... [z].
Ограничение двумя лишь союзами (если не ошибаюсь?) - как-то уж слишком скудоречиво.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В зависимости от контекста синонимами "или" еще могут быть следующие слова и выражения:

*иначе, иначе говоря, то есть, сиречь, по другому говоря*.